# Why does the y-axis of my distplot contain values up to 150?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem with the seaborn displot function most precisely on only 1 variable.
I've got

```
sns.distplot(df.abc, hist = True, norm_hist = True)
```

And this is what I get as a plot. Values in y-axis rising to 150+ (not normal)

[image: Values in y-axis rising to 150+ (not normal)]

On a side-note, I should add that my data isn't really weird in the sense that it shouldn't do that.
Here is the `describe()` of the data (As you can see, nothing too much out of the ordinary):

[image: describe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the high histogram values, there are two isues to take into account:

- Your distribution is discrete, while `distplot` is meant for continuous distributions. Maybe the distribution doesn't look discrete, but rounding to 3 digits makes that in this case you only have about 30 different values. Here some values get thrown into the same bin while the neighboring bin stays empty.  You can solve this by explicitly setting the bins. Note that as the kde averages out gaussian normal curves, the effect of the discrete distribution on the kde is rather limited.
- The histogram is normalized such that the total **area** sums to one. The area of a rectangle is its base multiplied by its height. In this case the width is about `0.001`, so about 20 bars with an average height of 50 would make the total area equal to 1.
- The [kde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) is a stand-in for the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and as such also has an area below the curve equal to 1. As the base is rather short (about `0.03`), the height needs to compensate (averaging about 33).

The following code calculates the sum of all bar areas, and also shows the effect of explicitly setting the bins (bin boundaries just in the center between values):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as  np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.normal(1.163974, 0.005552, 13484).round(3)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
for ax in axes:
    bins = None
    if ax == axes[1]:
        bins = np.arange(x.min() - 0.0005, x.max() + 0.0006, 0.001)
    ax = sns.distplot(x, bins=bins, hist=True, norm_hist=True, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor='k'), ax=ax)
    area = 0
    for p in ax.patches:
        h = p.get_height()
        w = p.get_width()
        area += w * h
    ax.set_title(f'{"default bins" if ax == axes[0] else "explicit bins"}, total area: {area:.2f}')
plt.show()
```

[image: comparison plot]

Here is another example:

```py
x = np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(1.155, 1.175, 10), 1000), 0.001).round(3)
```

[image: more complex example]